# What is the use of Subtracting velocity?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, displacement

By adding two velocity's direction we get the direction the object has travelled. But what do we get when we subtract vectors?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are observing from your point of view two objects, traveling in their own directions and at their own speeds. So you have two velocity vectors $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v_2}$.

By subtracting one from the other, you get the relative velocity between those objects: $\vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1$ will be the velocity of object 2 as observed by object 1 (assuming that we're not at super fast speeds where special relativity becomes important).

Answer (score 0):

One way to understand this is to realize that $\vec{v_1} -\vec{v_2}$ is basically adding $\vec{v_1}$ with $\vec{-v_2}$ i.e. $\vec{v_1} -\vec{v_2} = \vec{v_1} + (\vec{-v_2})$. So, as the first answer explained, if you have two cars $A$ and $B$ travelling east at velocities $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ respectively, the person sitting in car $B$ will see car $A$ moving at velocity $\vec{v_2} -\vec{v_1}$ which is the relative velocity.